# Iterating values of a Set

Tags: java

We have a collection - `Map<String,HashSet<String>> requestIdToproductMap`
It is meant to map a requestId to the productIds corresponding to the requestId.
Given a set of requestIds and a productId,we iterate through each key(requestId),to find if productId is present.
If yes,remove it and check if the values set becomes empty.

```
for (String reqId: requests) {
    Set<String> productIdset = requestIdToproductMap.get(reqId);
    productIdset.remove(productId);
    if (productIdset.isEmpty()) {
            //add requestId to discarded list
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this - given that this is a high volume operation?

Comment: Two things.  1)  You sure you don't have a Map?  2)  Considering that `reqId` is outside of the loop, there's no reason to recreate that set every time in the loop.

Comment: Add some data structure that allows you to quickly find the requestIds containing a certain productId.

Comment: @Makoto "there's no reason to recreate that set every time in the loop" - where is the set recreated?

Comment: What did you mean by re-create?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to retain your `Map<String,HashSet<String>> requestIdToproductMap`, and need to remove `productId` from all of the sets, I don't think there is a much better way to do it. You have to check all the sets of given `requests` and remove the `productId` from all of them - this is what you do.

Your code as it stands should be actually quite performant. `HashMap.get` (if you're using a `HashMap`) is amortized O(1), so is `HashSet.remove`. So the overall performance should be pretty good.

You could maybe consider a different data structure. Where insteadn of mapping `requestId` onto set of `productId`s you simply store pairs of `requestId`/`productId`. Implement a class like `RequestIdProductIdPair` (don't forget `equals(...)` and `hashCode()`). Then store `RequestIdProductIdPair`s in a `HashSet<RequestIdProductIdPair> requestIdProductIds`. You could then simply construct and remove all the given `requestId`/`productId` pairs.

```
Set<String> discardedRequestIds = requests
    .stream()
    .map(requestId -> new RequestIdProductIdPair(requestId, productId))
    .map(requestIdProductIdPair -> {
        if (requestIdProductIds.remove(requestIdProductIdPair) {
            return requestIdProductIdPair;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(RequestIdProductIdPair::getRequestId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Update:** I've thought about it a bit more and on the second thought I think the second option with `HashSet<RequestIdProductIdPair>` will probably not be better than your code. Removal will be probably somewhat more performant, but this code create a one new `RequestIdProductIdPair` object per `requestId`/`productId` pair. So it will probably end up being worse than your code.